# Expression expected при передаче List и Map в качестве аргументов

Tags: java

```
CreateUserTest newUser = new CreateUserTest(apiUrl, dn, keyName, keyPass, template,
                List<String> altDN, Map<String, Object> userdata, username, password);
```

В данном коде List и Map подчеркиваются красным и написано - Expression expeted. Что это значит? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

при передаче в конструктор нужно указывать только значение (без типов)

```
CreateUserTest newUser = new CreateUserTest(apiUrl, dn, keyName, keyPass, template,
                altDN, userdata, username, password);
```